# how to change logo using ant design module?

Tags: reactjs

I have this code in my app.jsx but I don't see where the link to the logo is?

```
import { Menu, Layout} from "antd";
<Header style={styles.header}>
          <Logo />
```

Comment: where dos `<Logo />` com from?

Comment: This will lead to error!